# SAP Fiori FPM/WebDynpro Apps Activation

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, webdynpro

I am new to SAP Fiori, I have been assigned to activate SAP Fiori apps on our SAP S/4HANA 1511 FPS02. I have activated all assigned transactional apps, Our launchpad is running fine, but I am unable to activate FPM/WebDynpro applications.

I have followed this [Link](https://websmp208.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100012043332015E.pdf) step by step, but I am unable to get my FPM/WebDynpro Apps.
Can someone guide me how to activate webdynpro Fiori apps.
​I have also tested and activated the webdynpro components from SICF, still I am unable to activate the tile.

WEbDynpro app eg: [DynproApp](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F1422')/S5OP)
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

​Eliza

​​

Comment: What error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the App Specific Technical Catalog is missing.You must be Experiencing Reference Error in Tile(Launchpad Designer) for your App Business Catalog.

Please refer note 2269272 and refer [Link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/52/2749ec852a4779845ee028e5b950a1/content.htm).

Regards,

Sayed